# React Native Theme App - Is there any way to change the text style outside of the React Native App

Tags: android, ios, swift, react-native, mobile-application

I have been working on a React-Native app and I am curious if I can change the text style of any text that user see on Safari while searching on web or reading an article etc.

Maybe by getting the HTML, configuring and injecting back to the current web page's HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  First off, react-native doesn't run in Safari or any other browser.  It uses native rendering.  Secondly, what you're asking for is basically if you can Man in The Middle attack any webpage.  No OS or browser would allow that, its basically installing malware.

Comment: That's true, it makes sense. Thanks! I think the way is to create a browser extension instead of a mobile app.